# problem with map view

Tags: iphone

I need to draw link from my current location to destination location.

current location latitude longitude=x,y;
destination location latitude longitude=a,b;

from my current location to destination location i need to draw path....

How can i do that.

help me out.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These can help you

http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65

http://iphonegeeksworld.wordpress.com/2010/09/08/drawing-routes-onto-mkmapview-using-unofficial-google-maps-directions-api/